# How to Remove virus completely from laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows

I recently tried to download some files from net without antivirus.Ever since I am having red traces all over my screen.Then I installed avast free version and run full scan but no improvement.Then I started my laptop in safe mode and started malware antimalware with full system scan.But it didn't remove.Please give me some suggestions so I can recover from this situation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by red traces? it's very unlikely the red traces were cause by a malicious file

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best way is to wipe everything out.  backup critical data to USB stick/hard drive.  dban 1 pass the whole drive.

Re-install windows and your software.
5-6 hours 
Done and clean

---

Buy a third party tool with a boot CD/USB stick maker like Norton antivirus.  Boot from there special CD/DVD/USB and scan your system with both tools.
Then maybe you will get maybe you wont.

If this does not get it prepare to spent 30 more hours with a variety of tools.

Comment: Nothing guarantees the malware isn't in your used data....

Comment: Correct, you still need to scan all your files with a variety of scanners on the data you saved.  Try virustotal.